# Реализация системы добавления в избранное зарегистрированным пользователем

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет! Никак не могу найти какую-либо информацию о реализации системы добавления в избранное для зарегистрированного пользователя.

В модели есть модель `Post`.
В ней пару полей формата `String`. Поле `author`, в котором указывается какой пользователь сделал `POST` запрос и тд.

Но как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог добавить этот Post к себе в "избранное", чтобы потом можно было получить JSON ответ со всеми постами, которые он добавил себе.
Ну и соответсвенно, чтобы можно было удалить из избранного.

Есть-ли какие-либо идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в модель Post добавить поле ManyToManyField с моделью User. И те кто будут добавлять себе Post в избранное будут создаваться в промежуточной таблице БД. В которой будет идентификатор поста и идентификатор пользователя. Что то вроде:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favorite_posts')
```

Для добавления постов избранное используется следующий код:

```
user.favorite_posts.add(Post.objects.get(id=1))
```

Для удаления:

```
user.favorite_posts.remove(Post.objects.get(id=1))
```

Достать все избранные посты:

```
user.favorite_posts.all()
```

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо большое за ответ. Но куда вставлять эти методы для добавления/удаления/отображения избранного?

Answer (score 1):

ну идея есть
добавить посту поле `favorites = models.BooleanField(default=False)`
добавить кнопку для поста избранное.
и написать обработчик этой кнопки который будет при нажатии менять значение поля favorites

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли вопрос

Comment: @TheGreatVY что конкретно не так я понял?

Comment: Здесь необходимо учесть, что я могу потом сделать запрос, к примеру, по URL "myLikes". И там я получу все посты, на которые поставил лайк. Ваша идея подразумевает только поле с булевым значением, просто показывая визуально стоит ли тут лайк или нет (это уже реализовано). Сама проблема в отображении в другом вью сете лайкнутых постов.

Comment: @TheGreatVY так а в чем проблема потом фильтровать? лайкнут пост или нет и передать в другой url лайкнутые.
Post.objects.filter(favorites__in=["True"])

Comment: Сможете, пожалуйста, показать как это реализовать кодом?